# From pandas object to date in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have this date in pandas, which is object `2016-01`. If iam trying to to `df["month"] = pd.to_datetime(df["month"])` it converts to date, but add days.

Is there a way in pandas or in sqlalchemy itself to convert years-month into date and then put that date into mysql database, without addings days  ?

Comment: You can convert it to a string and insert that. But a date object cannot exist without a day specified

Comment: So, there's no way for trasnfering to mysql server only year-month as date ?

Comment: theres no "year-month" object in mysql or in python - in the industry, the normal workaround is to just set the day to the first of the month, and then just use a normal date object